# C# listbox trying to split a selected item in the listbox to 2 seperate strings in 2 textboxes

Tags: c#

```
private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string stringToSplit = ListBox.SelectedIndex;

                string[] splitString;

                splitString = stringToSplit.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                textBoxName.Text = ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
```

Want to view the selected item in two textboxes.

Comment: So where is your second textbox? `SelectedIndex` is an `int` (an _index_), not the text displayed in the listbox. Simply split `ListBoxSelectedItem.ToString()` and put the results in your textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. This will split words using `,` as the separating character.

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] splitString;

        string stringToSplit = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();


        splitString = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(',');

        textBox2.Text = splitString[0];

        if (splitString.Length>1) {
            textBox3.Text = splitString[1];
        }
        else
        {
            textBox3.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Cheers for the help i have sorted it now.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a selected item as a string from `ListBox` you can use the `SelectedItem` property instead of `SelectedIndex`.

Also, when you have the only single separator, then you don't need an array of chars. you can use the first overload of the `split` function.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stringToSplit = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var splitString =  stringToSplit.Split(',');

    textBox1.Text = splitString[0];
    textBox2.Text = splitString.Length > 1 ? splitString[1] : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have solved the issue now.